# Spreadsheet using devanagari numbers

Tags: libreoffice, unicode

Spreadsheets allow for inputting Devanagari characters but the functions such as SUM etc. still expect English numbers. The equivalent Devanagari characters - १, २,३ ..... are not used as numbers in evaluation of functions.

Is there a way to make the functions work with Devanagari numbers.

Is there a way to develop a variant of Hindi keyboard that displays numbers in Devanagari but the actual storage is in ASCII, just as DATE is internally stored as a number but displayed in many defined formats. In this case the existing functions will continue to work as before.

Does anyone know of a solution to the above?

Answer (score 1):

Under `Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Complex Text Layout`, there is a drop-down box to select the type of numeral.  There is even an option called "Hindi."  However, **this is not Devanagari**.  Instead, Wikipedia calls these numbers [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals).

It seems strange that the list is limited to two types of numerals.  I suggest filing an enhancement request to add Devanagari numerals to the list (and perhaps other numerals as well).  Then it should do everything you are asking.

There is also an entry called "System" in the list.  So I tried setting my system to use Devanagari numerals.  However this did not affect LibreOffice.  As explained in [the documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.4/Common/Complex_Text_Layout#Numerals_.28in_text_only.29), this only chooses between Arabic and Hindi.